# Attach Interrupt with Library

Tags: interrupt, library

I am trying to make a library for Arduino, which requires an interruption, but the problem is that when I try the `attachInterrupt` function inside my library, there's a problem about attachInterrupt is static. Right now, in the library I have this in the header file:

```
#ifndef RegletaCMA_h
#define RegletaCMA_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class DimmerGlider {
public:
    DimmerGlider(int min, int max, int increase);

    int getMin() { return _min; }

    int getMax() { return _max; }

    int getIncrease() { return _increase; }

    void setMin(int min) { _min = min; }

    void setMax(int max) { _max = max; }

    void setIncrease(int increase) { _increase = increase; }

private:
    int _min, _max, _increase;
};

class Dimmer {

public:
    Dimmer(DimmerGlider &glider, int outputPin, int t3);

    void Dimmer::begin() {
        pinMode(_outputPin, OUTPUT);
        digitalWrite(_outputPin, false);
    }

    void Dimmer::dim() {
        delayMicroseconds(_DIMMER_counter);
        digitalWrite(_outputPin, true);  // Turn _DIMMER_pinDimmer on
        delayMicroseconds(_t3);
        digitalWrite(_outputPin, false); // Turn _DIMMER_pinDimmer off

        if (_DIMMER_dir) _DIMMER_counter += _glider.getIncrease(); // If dir is negative add _DIMMER_increase
        else _DIMMER_counter -= _glider.getIncrease();                  // If dir is negative substract _DIMMER_increase

        if (_DIMMER_counter > _glider.getMax()) _DIMMER_dir = false; // Change dir if reached bottom
        if (_DIMMER_counter < _glider.getMin()) _DIMMER_dir = true;  // Change dir if reached top

        _DIMMER_lastExecutionTime_micros = micros(); // Reset timer
    }

    void Dimmer::force(bool status) {
        digitalWrite(_outputPin, status);
    }

private:
    DimmerGlider &_glider;

    int _outputPin;

    int _DIMMER_counter = 1000;
    bool _DIMMER_dir = true;

    unsigned long long _DIMMER_lastExecutionTime_micros = 0;

    int _t3;
};

class DimmerImplementor {
public:
    DimmerImplementor(Dimmer dimmerList[], int optoPin);

    void DimmerImplementor::begin(){
        attachInterrupt(_optoPin, dimAll, RISING);
    }

    void DimmerImplementor::dimAllDimmers() {
        for (int c = 0; c < sizeof(_dimmerList); c++)
            _dimmerList[c].dim();
    }

    void DimmerImplementor::dimAll() {
        DimmerImplementor::dimAllDimmers();
    }

private:
    int _optoPin;
    Dimmer _dimmerList[];
};

#endif
```

and this in the cpp file:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "RegletaCMA.h"

DimmerGlider::DimmerGlider(int min, int max, int increase) :
        _min(min),
        _max(max),
        _increase(increase) {
}

Dimmer::Dimmer(DimmerGlider &glider, int outputPin, int t3) :
        _glider(glider),
        _outputPin(outputPin),
        _t3(t3) {
}

DimmerImplementor::DimmerImplementor(Dimmer *dimmerList, int optoPin) :
        _dimmerList(dimmerList),
        _optoPin(optoPin) {
    for(int c = 0; c < sizeof(dimmerList); c++){
        DimmerImplementor::dimmers[c] = dimmerList[c];
    }

    for (int c = 0; c < sizeof(dimmers); c++) {
        Dimmer dimmer = dimmers[c];

        dimmer.begin();
    }
}
```

and when I try to run the library with the Arduino IDE, with this code:

```
DimmerGlider dimmer1Glider = DimmerGlider(_DIMMER_1_tempMin, _DIMMER_1_tempMax, _DIMMER_1_increase);
Dimmer dimmer1 = Dimmer(
                   dimmer1Glider,
                   _DIMMER_1_pin,
                   _DIMMER_t3
                 );
DimmerGlider dimmer2Glider = DimmerGlider(_DIMMER_2_tempMin, _DIMMER_2_tempMax, _DIMMER_2_increase);
Dimmer dimmer2 = Dimmer(
                   dimmer2Glider,
                   _DIMMER_2_pin,
                   _DIMMER_t3
                 );
DimmerGlider dimmer3Glider = DimmerGlider(_DIMMER_3_tempMin, _DIMMER_3_tempMax, _DIMMER_3_increase);
Dimmer dimmer3 = Dimmer(
                   dimmer3Glider,
                   _DIMMER_3_pin,
                   _DIMMER_t3
                 );

Dimmer dimmers[] = {
  dimmer1, dimmer2, dimmer3
};

DimmerImplementor implementor = DimmerImplementor(dimmers, _DIMMER_pinOpto);

void Dimmer_Init() {
  implementor.begin();
}
```

It throws the following error:

```
C:\Users\Arnym\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RegletaCMA/RegletaCMA.h: In member function 'void DimmerImplementor::begin()':

C:\Users\Arnym\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RegletaCMA/RegletaCMA.h:73:44: error: invalid use of non-static member function

         attachInterrupt(_optoPin, dimAll, 3); // 3 is the same as RISING

                                            ^
```

I have been messing around with this problem for some days and I can't find an answer, so I would be really pleased if you can help me.
If you need any more info, don't doubt on asking.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, you need to distinguish between two separate copies of an object, or having a reference to an existing object. @chrisl got it right when he identified that you were trying to create a second copy of `DimmerGlider`, so he suggested using a reference - and then showed using a pointer (`*`) instead.

He was right: `Dimmer` should hold a *reference* to the `DimmerGlider` object, but that is done with `&`. You need to make the following changes to the given code:

In the `.h`:

```
class Dimmer {

public:
    Dimmer(DimmerGlider &glider, int outputPin, int t3);
.
.
.
private:
    DimmerGlider &_glider;
.
.
```

And in the final `.cpp`:

```
DimmerGlider::DimmerGlider(int min, int max, int increase) :
              _min(min),
              _max(max),
              _increase(increase) {
}

Dimmer::Dimmer(DimmerGlider &glider, int outputPin, int t3) :
        _glider(glider),
        _outputPin(outputPin),
        _t3(t3) {
}
```

The syntax for the `Dimmer` constructor had to change. You were *assigning* the class members the values from the constructor parameters. References need to be ***initialised***, not assigned. This is the syntax you need (note how they’re before the `{`?)

I fixed the `DimmerGlider` constructor code while I was at it...

Also, note the difference between using a reference versus using a pointer. A pointer needs to be dereferenced, so you need to use `*ptr` and `ptr->_min` to refer to the original object. A reference is *already* dereferenced, so you can simply use it like the original object: `ref` and `ref._min`.

---

Edit: If you want to use the function `dimAll()` as an interrupt handler function, then it cannot be a (non-`static`) member of a `class`. All `class` functions have a hidden `this` pointer as the first parameter in the argument list, since it has to know *which* `DimmerImplementor`'s members to modify. Thus you have to declare the function as `static`. And as soon as you do that, you cannot call `dimAllDimmers()`, because that functions accesses an instance of `DimmerImplementor`'s variables. Luckily, you have a global object called `implementor`, so you could use that:

```
static void DimmerImplementor::dimAll() {
    implementor.dimAllDimmers();
}
```

But it's usual to make that variable a `static` member of the class itself:

```
class DimmerImplementor {
    .
    .
public: // Static variables
    static DimmerImplementor implementor;
    .
    .
}; // DimmerImplementor
```

You'd initialise that as follows:

```
DimmerImplementor DimmerImplementor::implementor(dimmers, _DIMMER_pinOpto);
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my first problem, but I am still having troubles with attachInterrupt, the compiler throws `error: invalid use of non-static member function`, see modified question for the full program

Comment: @ArnyminerZ Check the edit to my answer

Answer (score 0):

The error message says, that in the constructor of `Dimmer` it cannot find a matching constructor of `DimmerGlider`. The problem here is that you pass the parameters by value, which will create a new variable of the given type and content for the function/constructor call. So when you create a new `Dimmer` variable you are calling the constructor of the class. Since the parameters of the constructor contain a `DimmerGlider` instance, it also has to be created for you, which means calling the constructor. When passing variables by value the default constructor (without any parameters) is used. But the `DimmerGlider` doesn't have a default constructor (as you didn't define it). The compiler then tells you, that is needs some parameters for the constructor to create a `DimmerGlider` instance.

I don't know a way to pass these parameters for the `DimmerGlider` constructor directly through the `Dimmer` constructor. Also I don't think this is desirable for you. You are creating the `DimmerGlider` first and sure want the `Dimmer` objects to refer to exactly this instance, not a different (cloned) instance, that was created with the `Dimmer` constructor.

So my suggestion is the following: Pass the `DimmerGlider` by reference, meaning you only pass a pointer to the `DimmerGlider` object. In the constructor definition of `Dimmer` change to the following:

```
Dimmer::Dimmer(DimmerGlider *glider, int outputPin, int t3);
```

The `*` says, that this variable will not hold an instance of the `DimmerGlider` class, but only a pointer to one. A pointer is simple to create, because it is basically an `unsigned int` (a 16 bit memory address).

Then in your sketch you are passing not the variable itself, but only the address in memory (a pointer to the object) by using the `&`:

```
Dimmer dimmer1 = Dimmer(
                   &dimmer1Glider,
                   _DIMMER_1_pin,
                   _DIMMER_t3
                 );
```

Now the constructor of `Dimmer` doesn't have to create an instance of `DimmerGlider`, but only a simple pointer of the type `Dimmerglider`. The `&` retrieves the memory address (the pointer) of an object instance. The constructor now simply writes the pointer, that it got as a parameter, into the `glider` variable of type `DimmerGlider`-pointer.

If you don't understand, how pointers work, please google for a tutorial on this. This isn't something, that can be easily explained in the short question-answer format of this site.

Comment: But that constructor should be the Dimmer constructor, not the DimmerGlider one

Comment: The constructor you sent, is the Dimmer one, as specified on the line 29 of the header file:

`Dimmer(DimmerGlider glider, int outputPin, int t3);`

and then initialized in the cpp file:

`Dimmer::Dimmer(DimmerGlider glider, int outputPin, int t3) {
    _glider = glider;
    _outputPin = outputPin;
    _t3 = t3;
}`

The DimmerGlider class only needs three int parameters:

`DimmerGlider::DimmerGlider(int min, int max, int increase)`

Comment: You are right, I haven't seen that, But now I rellay understand whats happening there. I will change my answer.